# Send raw data to virtual PDF printer

Tags: c#, virtual-printer

I found this [class](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091) in microsoft suport, explaining how to send a raw data to printer... but, when I try to use this to print in virtual PDF printer, not work.
I tested wth foxit pdf printer and pdf creator..
I made some changes in the code, as authorizing print to file and etc, but nothing worked.

How can it be made ​​to work, sending the RawData for virtual printer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to send raw data to the printer in the printer's native formatting language such as PCL or Postscript.  Many virtual printers do not have an underlying formatting language, so raw printing won't work.  Some virtual printers such as "PDF Creator" uses Ghostcript, which supports Postscript.  Sending raw Postscript to "PDF Creator" may work.

Comment: Hi, and how can i convert or prepare a text to postcript?